# How can I seal a smoker door?

Tags: fireplace, woodstove

I am building a brick smoker and need to seal between the door (a small panel on the top of the firebox) and the bricks.

What kind of material is appropriate here? I was thinking some kind of flexible rubber gasket, maybe the kind used to make custom gaskets for engines?

Comment: Have you considered removing and re-using the seals from an old oven?

Comment: I would not use any gaskets that are made for engines as they probably off gas some nasty stuff when heated.  Look for something that is food safe, not sure it needs to be high heat safe since smoking doesn't use high heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this: [Woodstove Gasket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000S6TMUU) It worked well on my woodstove.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. From there I found the term 'rope gasket' which in conjunction with RV seal maker (what I was originally thinking) should do the job nicely.